# How to identify ≥ or ≤ in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba

This is probably a simple question but I just can't figure it out.

I've built a macro to convert values in Celsius to Fahrenheit in a range. The problem is, sometimes these comes with > or < than, and sometimes with ≥ or ≤ signs. I can not figure out a way to get VBA to recognize the ≥ or ≤ signs at all. I've tried ASCII and unicode and neither seems to be working.

I've included the code here (With my attempts at Unicode in place of the ≥ or ≤ symbols)

As it stands, it just replaces those symbols with nothing at all instead of putting them back into place.

```
Sub Celsius_to_Fahrenheit()
Set myRange = Selection
    For Each myCell In myRange
    LastString = ""
    GTLT = ""
    For i = 1 To Len(myCell.Value)
        mt = Mid(myCell.Value, i, 1)
        If mt Like "[0-9]" Or mt Like "-" Or mt Like "." Then
            tstring = mt
            ElseIf mt Like "–" Or mt Like "—" Then
            tstring = "-"
            ElseIf mt Like ">" Or mt Like "<" Or mt Like ChrW(U + 2264) Or mt Like ChrW(U + 2265) Then
            GTLT = mt
            tstring = ""
        Else
            tstring = ""
        End If
        LastString = LastString & tstring
    Next i
    myCell.Value = GTLT & 32 + (9 / 5) * LastString & " °F"
Next

Selection.Replace What:="-", Replacement:="–", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="111111111111", Replacement:="1", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="222222222222", Replacement:="2", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="333333333333", Replacement:="3", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="444444444444", Replacement:="4", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="555555555555", Replacement:="5", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="666666666666", Replacement:="6", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="777777777777", Replacement:="7", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="888888888888", Replacement:="8", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
Selection.Replace What:="999999999999", Replacement:="9", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False

Selection.Replace What:="° °", Replacement:=" °", LookAt:=xlPart, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False, ReplaceFormat:=False
```

End Sub

Comment: Try ChrW(&H2264) and  ChrW(&H2265)

Comment: Or try `ChrW(8804)` and `ChrW(8805)`. And why are you using `Like` and not `=`. I can understand it for `[0-9]` but not the others. I suspect `Like` is much slower than `=` and you have to be careful because some characters such as `"."` have special meanings in regular expressions.